# LibGDX: AssetsManager GdxRuntimeException when disposing it

Tags: java, libgdx

Hello I have a problem with the `AssetsManager` from libGDX.

I load a `TTF` and a `Skin` with a `AssetsManager` and add the `TTF` to the `Skin`. Then when I **dispose** the `AssetsManager` it throws a exception.

I know the problem should be that the skin and asssets manager do dispose the same pixmap. But is there a way to prevent this to happen?

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Pixmap already disposed!
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.dispose(Pixmap.java:315)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PixmapPacker$Page$1.dispose(PixmapPacker.java:384)
```

Code:

```
    FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter ttfParam = new FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    ttfParam.fontFileName = Const.TTF_ARIAL_PATH;

    if (!manager.isLoaded(Const.TTF_ARIAL_SMALL, BitmapFont.class)) {
        ttfParam.fontParameters.size = 16;

        manager.load(Const.TTF_ARIAL_SMALL, BitmapFont.class, ttfParam);
    }

    if (!manager.isLoaded(Const.TTF_ARIAL_NORMAL, BitmapFont.class)) {
        ttfParam.fontParameters.size = 32;

        manager.load(Const.TTF_ARIAL_NORMAL, BitmapFont.class, ttfParam);
    }

    if (!manager.isLoaded(Const.TTF_ARIAL_LARGE, BitmapFont.class)) {
        ttfParam.fontParameters.size = 64;

        manager.load(Const.TTF_ARIAL_LARGE, BitmapFont.class, ttfParam);
    }

    if (!manager.isLoaded(Const.EDITOR_UI_SKIN, Skin.class)) {
        SkinParameter skinParam = new SkinParameter(Const.EDITOR_UI_SKIN_PATH);
        manager.load(Const.EDITOR_UI_SKIN, Skin.class, skinParam);
    }

    manager.finishLoading();

    skin = manager.get(Const.EDITOR_UI_SKIN, Skin.class);

    BitmapFont font = manager.get(Const.TTF_ARIAL_SMALL, BitmapFont.class);
    skin.add(Const.TTF_ARIAL_SMALL, font, BitmapFont.class);
```

EDIT: I solved it. But I don't like the solution.

```
public void dispose() {
    skin.remove(Const.TTF_ARIAL_SMALL, BitmapFont.class);
    manager.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the asset is not needed anymore and you want to free it to avoid memory leaks. use :

```
manager.unload( yourAsset ) ;
```

It is interesting to point out if you want to free all assets, no matter whether
queued or loaded, at once, instead of doing it one by one:

```
manager.clear() ;
```

Nevertheless, by using the clear( ) method, AssetManager is still alive, finally:

```
manager.dispose
```